# Reproduce UITableViewCell style

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How may I reproduce the message UITableViewCell style, without using custom cells ?

For the moment, I am using UICellStyleWithSubtitle, and I add accessories, but I can only see the date, and the UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator is hidden.

What I want :

> http://www.askdavetaylor.com/4-blog-pics/iphone-text-txt-message-haiti-2.png

What I am doing :

```
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 15)];
    [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [table returnDate]]];
    [myLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    cell.accessoryView = myLabel;
    [myLabel release]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = table.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = table.subtitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [table returnDate]
```

instead of using label simply assign the value to *detailTextLabel*, and give cell style as *UITableViewCellStyleValue1*.

Comment: Here u set the label as _accessoryView_, so it hides the indicator. Try to add the label as _accessoryView_ **subView**.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you don't have to use UICellStyleWithSubtitle..u could use UITableViewCellStyleValue1 and try with detailTextLabel property of cell like:
`cell.detailTextLabel.text  = @"Yesterday";`